# Android: How can I set mMultiWindowStyle of Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

While I'm debuging my application on Note 3 Kitkat and launching my application via MultiWindow Tray-bar, I receive an Intent with a value named 'mMultiWindowStyle', see the picture.

What mMultiWindowStyle is? And how it can be set?[image]